# Is it possible to prove empty set uniqueness in FOL directly (without proof by contradiction)

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

So I have a partial proof of uniqueness of the empty set in FOL:

1. $\exists x \forall z(z \notin x)$ (ZF2)
2. $z_1 \notin e_1 $ (Universal & Existential Instantiation of (1))
3. $z_1 \notin e_2 $ (Same)
4. $z_1 \in e_1 \rightarrow z_1 \in e_2$ (Tautology $\neg A \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)$)
5. $z_1 \in e_2 \rightarrow z_1 \in e_1$ (Same)
6. $\forall z (z \in e_1 \rightarrow z \in e_2)$ (Uni Generalization)
7. $\forall z (z \in e_2 \rightarrow z \in e_1)$ (Same)
8. $\forall z (z \in e_1 \rightarrow z \in e_2) \land \forall z (z \in e_2 \rightarrow z \in e_1)$ (Conj Intro)
9. $\forall z (z \in e_1 \rightarrow z \in e_2 \land z \in e_2 \rightarrow z \in e_1)$ (Identity)
10. $\forall z (z \in e_1 \leftrightarrow z \in e_2)$ (Biconditional Intro)
11. $e_1 = e_2$ (Eq Intro)

So far, so good. But what I actually want to prove is:
$$\forall x \forall y [(\forall z (z \notin x) \land \forall z (z \notin y)) \rightarrow x = y] .....P$$

As hard as I try, I can't go from (1)-(11) to $P$.

Basically where I'm struggling is turning the $e$'s into $\forall$ statements. Since $e$'s are constants, we can only do existential generalization, not universal generalization. I guess my question boils down to whether there is some theorem that allows us to go from constants/existential quantifiers to universal ones. My suspect is "$(\exists x P(x))\rightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $\forall x (P \rightarrow Q)$ (as long as $x$ is not in $Q$)", but I can't seem to put the pieces together in the right way. ;)

Everyone seems to agree that it is possible to prove empty set uniqueness directly (e.g. [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694978/is-it-possible-to-prove-uniqueness-without-using-proof-by-contradiction)), but I can't find a proof myself...

Comment: The uniqueness of the empty set needs Extensionality.

Comment: The empty set is an object that "lives" in set theory; thus you needs the axioms of set theory to manage it.

Comment: Yes, I believe I'm using that in Step 11. I should have said I am also using axioms of Set theory.

Comment: The question is still the same: is it possible to deduce the theorem directly, only using FOL + set theory axioms?

Comment: Yes: using Extensionality,

Comment: Can you show it? Or tell me if my proof is valid :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it!

I'm going to write a bunch of implications and then join the first and last:

$\quad \forall z (z \notin x) \land \forall z (z \notin y)$

$\rightarrow \forall z (z \notin x), \forall z (z \notin y)$ (Conj Elim)

$\rightarrow z \notin x, z \notin y$ (Univ Inst)

$\rightarrow z \in x \rightarrow z \in y, z \in y \rightarrow z \in x$ (Tautology $\neg A \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B))$

$\rightarrow z \in x \rightarrow z \in y \land z \in y \rightarrow z \in x$ (Conj Intro)

$\rightarrow \forall z (z \in x \rightarrow z \in y \land z \in y \rightarrow z \in x)$ (Univ Gen)

$\rightarrow \forall z(z\in x \leftrightarrow z\in y)$ (Biconditional Intro)

$\rightarrow x=y$ (Eq Intro/Axiom of Ext)

Hence:

$$(\forall z (z \notin x) \land \forall z (z \notin y)) \rightarrow x=y$$

So, by universal generalization

$$\forall x \forall y [(\forall z (z \notin x) \land \forall z (z \notin y)) \rightarrow x=y]$$

Comment: Correct........

Comment: Cool, thank you!!